# What does chrUn mean in the output from a Bowtie run on human sequences?

Tags: dna-sequencing, sequence-alignment, human-genome

After having performed an [alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment) using [bowtie2](http://bowtie-bio.sourceforge.net/bowtie2/index.shtml) and [GRCh38](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/news/12-23-2013-grch38-released/) as a reference sequence, I got inusual matches on `chrUn`.
Here a small part of the [SAM file](http://genome.sph.umich.edu/wiki/SAM):

```
@SQ     SN:chr22   LN:50818468
@SQ     SN:chrX    LN:156040895
@SQ     SN:chrY    LN:57227415
@SQ     SN:chrM    LN:16569
@SQ     SN:chrUn_KI270424v1     LN:2140
```

All the other `chr` values are clear to me (M indicates the Mitochondrial DNA, while 22, Y and X are just the usual chromosomes number/name) but I couldn't figure out what `chrUn` stands for and what about that code after the `_`?

Comment: Usually "Unknown". Sequences that have not been assigned to one of the chromosomes. I think this is from the Human genome, which has multiple sequences not assigned to a chromosome, so they have identifiers (the KI...)

Comment: @skymningen Thank you. If you add a reference and post it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: There is no reference for this, other than experience, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

I presume *chrUn_KI270424v1* refers to a scaffold or sequence that has not yet been assigned to a chromosome. The designation after the *Un* (unknown or unassigned?) may refer to a particular single sequence or a scaffold. You will be able to determin this by examining the reference sequence and its documentation.

(My assumption is based on the sort of thing one finds in the various versions of *Drosophila* reference genomes, with which I am familiar. So I can’t help you with the specifics of the human genome.)

Answer (score 3):

It is for unassigned sequences. See this reference from the UCSC Genome Browser FAQ: https://genome.ucsc.edu/FAQ/FAQdownloads.html#download11